# Django is not able to read the data posted from the POSTMAN?

Tags: python, django, postman

I have the following code snippet:-

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
# Create your views here.

@csrf_exempt
def ajax_post_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        foo = request.POST.get('Foo')
        print(foo)
        return JsonResponse(foo, safe=False)
    else:
        return JsonResponse("Not a POST method", safe=False)
```

And I am making a POST request from POSTMAN which showls null value in response:-
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried a curl command just to make sure its not postman

Comment: curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"Foo": "Bar", "email": "linuxize@example.com"}' \
    http://localhost:8080/ajax_post_view

Comment: The above curl command gives me None

Comment: Can you share your `urls.py`?

Comment: path('ajax_post_view', core_views.ajax_post_view, name="ajax_post_view"),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a propper endpoint. You need to use something like Django rest framework

This would be the most simple way to do it
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#function-based-views

Comment: How do I do it without using DRF?

Comment: or django-tastypie

Comment: I want it in raw django without any external libraries !!

Comment: well then you need a webpage to call it.

Comment: Cant I do it without web page you mean to say?

Comment: Without a rest framework or library Django can only be used as a webapp. So if you want  your backend to work without a rest framework you will  need to render a webpage